# React & Material UI: Position <IconButton> on bottom right of <Paper> (No FAB)

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

**Problem**:

I have a react/material-ui implementation where I would like to display a edit icon floating over the bottom right corner of a paper. I have figured out how I can have it floating on the bottom right of the overall screen but this is not what I am aiming for here.

**Current Behaviour:**

[image]

**Expected Behavior**: 
[image]

Have the Icon Button floating over the bottom right corner of the paper component.

```
<Paper classnName={classes.paper}>

    <IconButton
      onClick={handleVisionEditCick}
      style={{ position: "???", bottom: 3, right: 3 }}
     >
        <EditIcon className={classes.EditIcon} />
    </IconButton>
    <Typography variant="h5" component="span" color="textPrimary">
         {vision}
    </Typography>
</Paper>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's maybe not the best solution, but you can try using Grid

```
      <Grid container justify="flex-end" alignItems="flex-end">
        <IconButton style={{ bottom: 3, right: 3 }}>
          <Edit className={classes.EditIcon} />
        </IconButton>
      </Grid>
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-yalow-6xpcc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
It is "somewhat" what I was looking for as this positions it within the paper, in comparison to "over the corner". 

I added a mockup about what I mean to the description.